# JAVA: scan specific network for host name

Tags: java, networking, virtual-machine, ip-address

I've [had problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552840/bamboo-remote-build-agent-does-not-find-local-vm) finding a local VM with a private host-only network, trying to acquire it like this:

```
private static void printUvms(String domainName, String pattern)
{
    InetAddress[] addresses = null;
    try
    {
        addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(domainName);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unknown Host: " + domainName);
        return;
    }

    for (InetAddress address : addresses)
    {
        System.out.println("Host Name: " + address.getHostName());
        System.out.println("Host Address: " + address.getHostAddress());
        if (address.getHostAddress().startsWith(pattern))
        {
            System.out.println("UVM found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here, domainName would be the VM's name ("UVM") and pattern would be "192.168." since it's a host-only network.

For some reason, even though the VM has the correct name and is listed with a 192.168.[i].[j] address when I run "arp -a" in the windows console, it sometimes does not find this VM, but sometimes it does.
When it does not, it instead finds a different VM with the same name somewhere that is connected to the network, and if it does, it only finds the local one. Never both however, which I find confusing given that I try to "getAllByName".

So I tried a different approach that looks like this:

```
private static String getUvm(String domainName, String pattern)
{
    String host = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("Checking %s%d...", pattern, i));
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
        {
            host = String.format("%s%d.%d", pattern, i, j);
            InetAddress address = null;
            try
            {
                address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                if (address.getHostName().equals(domainName))
                {
                    System.out.println("Host Name: " + address.getHostName());
                    System.out.println("Host Address: " + address.getHostAddress());
                    System.out.println("UVM found!");
                    return host;
                }
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Unknown Host: " + domainName);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Obviously this is a very time-consuming method and not something I can use in the end. 
If somebody could tell me how to do this in a better and more effective way, I'd highly appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at Java doc, there is a method:

*static InetAddress[] getAllByName(String host)*

And explanation:

*Given the name of a host, returns an array of its IP addresses, based on the configured name service on the system.*

So you can do this ,here are simple codes:

```
List<> list = ..;
InetAddress[] inetAddress = InetAddress[] getAllByName(your domainName){}
for(InetAddress : inetAddress) {
    list.add(inetAddress.getHostAddress().startWith("192.168"));
}
```

Comment: that's what i tried with my first approach, but it does not return me all hosts with the specified name.
there's 2 VMs I can find, both are called "UVM". the local one with an address starting with 192.168. (the one i want to find), and a second one somewhere in the network (which does NOT start with 192.168.).

I print all the VMs I find with the specified name that are returned by InetAddress.getAllByName, however I always only find one of them. Even though the address of both are listed when I execute the windows "arp -a" command in the command line.

Comment: And I check the source code , I found that this method <i>getAllByName</i> ,if you put a hostname param ,it will execute <i>getAllByName0</i> method which is private and static in InetAddress.class.In this method , first it will execute <i>getCachedAddresses</i> method then move on .Obviously ,it looks like cache  and the hostname which you put is the key.You can only find one ,maybe it is key-pair structure.

Comment: and there are some noticeable things:/* If it gets here it is presumed to be a hostname */
        /* Cache.get can return: null, unknownAddress, or InetAddress[] */

        /* make sure the connection to the host is allowed, before we
         * give out a hostname
         */

Comment: those are some interesting insights. i'll look further into that, thanks a lot